# facebook webhooks, lead ads, api, login flow

Tags: facebook, api, authentication, webhooks

I am trying to write webhooks to have facebook send lead ads into my online database (this is all server to server).
I finally have facebook surfing into my server and sending me a json stream with a leadgen_id.
I was told that I first need to login to facebook before downloading leads.
I am trying to login with the following:
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/oauth/access_token?client_id={my app id}&redirect_uri=https://fb-dev.leadmanager.co.il/FacebookLogin.ashx/&client_secret={app secret}&code=

I am not sure about the code and I am also not sure about the return_uri (because it is server to server)
When I run the URL from visual studio (or from internet explorer) i receive error 400.
when i try to open the url in firefox i receive: {
   "error": {
      "message": "Invalid verification code format.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 100,
      "fbtrace_id": "HT2e9itVrSF"
   }
}

Any idea?
Thanks
Moshe Rubenstein

Answer (score 0):

If you are receiving the leadgen_id from facebook in the json format, then all you need to do retrieve the lead information is query the lead_id with the access token using the API.  The call will look something like this:

https://facebook.developers.facebook.com/v2.7/leadgen_id?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

The access token required for a successful api call will need to be generated by someone with admin access on the page under which the lead was generated.

You can see more details on the api here- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/lead-ads/leads/v2.6#bulk-read